# Merge multiline logs with Datadog agent

Tags: xml, parsing, logging, datadog

I'm using Datadog agent for collecting my app's logs.
This is the pattern of my logs:

> [12/03/2023 | 15:57:15.951438] | LOG_MESSAGE

In my app, the logger sometimes print XML content. Here's an example:

> [12/03/2023 | 15:57:15.951438] | <Elements>...</Elements>

Sometimes, some of my logs that print XML content are just too long, and the logger is printing the message into 2 different lines:

> [12/03/2023 | 15:57:15.951438] | <Elements>...
> [12/03/2023 | 15:57:15.951438] | ...</Elements>

How can I edit the conf.yml file to merge the 2 logs together, and drop the prefix of the LOG_MESSAGE of the second log, containing the end of the XML file?

> [12/03/2023 | 15:57:15.951438] | </Elements>...</Elements>

Thanks!